# Recursion find all paths in graph matrix DFS

Tags: c, recursion, matrix, depth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a two functions based on Depth First Search using a recursion method. I'm ultimately trying to compare the runtime against warshall's algorithm (which I already have working). When I print my matrix it's off by a couple off paths.

The recursion is what may be throwing me off, it's my weakness. Because of the top if statement `if(iIndex1 == iIndex2) return TRUE;`, when I try to find if there is a path from (A,A), (B,B), (C,C), etc. I will always get `1` even if there is no path from A to A.

```
typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE } bool;

/* Recursive function will determine if there is a path from index 1 to 2
 * Based of DFS
 */
bool recPathExists( Graph G, int iIndex1, int iIndex2 )
{
    int j;
    G.nodeArray[iIndex1].visited = TRUE;
    if(iIndex1 == iIndex2){
            return TRUE;
    }
    for(j = 0; j < G.iNumNodes; j++){
        if(!G.nodeArray[j].visited && G.adjMatrix[iIndex1][j]==1){
            if(recPathExists(G, j, iIndex2))
                return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

/* Write a function to find all pairs of nodes which have paths between them.
 * Store this information in the provided pathMatrix.
 */
void allPathsRecFunc( Graph G , int **pathMatrix )
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < G.iNumNodes; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < G.iNumNodes; j++){
            if(recPathExists(G, i , j)== TRUE){
                pathMatrix[i][j] = 1;
            }
            resetVisited(G); //resets all nodes to FALSE
        }
    }
}
```

what it should be

```
A   0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
B   0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 
C   0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 
D   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
E   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
F   0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 
G   0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 
H   0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

what I get

```
A   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
B   0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 
C   0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 
D   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
E   0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
F   0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 
G   0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 
H   0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: "wrong results": *wrong* in which way? By the way, try to be consistent about the use of `{}` (I recommend always using them, even for single-statement loops), and: if recursion is the answer, usually a mostly imperative language like C isn't the tool of choice.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I know what the final matrix should be by using warshall's algorithm. I'm using this to compare it to the results of the matrix I'm getting through this method. The matrix is showing 1's where some 0's should be and vice versa. Only about half of it is accurate.

Comment: @hnefatl A recursive function is used to determine if there is a path in the graph from the node at iIndex1 to the node at iIndex2, based on the algorithm on DFS.  A for loop is needed to check all adjacent nodes. I will also need to mark nodes visited as I find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may be here:

```
for(j = 0; j < G.iNumNodes; j++)
{
    if(!G.nodeArray[j].visited && G.adjMatrix[iIndex1][j] == 1)
    {
        return recPathExists(G, j, iIndex2);
    }
}
```

By `return`ing the result of recursing on `recPathExists`, you're not checking the other possible nodes that could be reachable in the loop (in essence, you're returning failure too early, and missing possible paths).

I believe you want just a little modification:

```
for(j = 0; j < G.iNumNodes; j++)
{
    if(!G.nodeArray[j].visited && G.adjMatrix[iIndex1][j] == 1)
    {
        if (recPathExists(G, j, iIndex2))
            return TRUE;
    }
}
```

That is, "if a path does exist, return as we've found it. If not, keep looking".

Comment: okay that seems to have worked. The only issue I have left is because of the if statement at the top `if(iIndex1 == iIndex2)` when I have say (A,A) (B,B) (C,C) etc. they will always be 1 even if there is no path for (A,A) . I'm struggling to see what I can add to the if statement to avoid that.

Comment: @below_avg_st Cleanest way would probably be to make a wrapper function that calls your existing function. In your wrapper, check that if `iIndex1 == iIndex2`, then also `G.adjMatrix[iIndex1][iIndex2]==1` (that there's a loop). If not, call your existing function. In general, if you have a special case at the start, just add a step before the start to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

My depth first search uses recursion but it outputs a parent array, though the functionality should be the same. It got a perfect grade so I know it works. Hope it helps.

https://github.com/grantSwalwell/Data-Structures/blob/master/Depth%20First%20Search.h

Algorithm~

1. bool array, visited for flagging nodes
2. search number array to measure the depth of access
3. depth to increment and come up with search num
4. Call DFS on 0,0
5. For each non visited neighbor
6. DFS depth + 1, search = depth, visited = true
7. return parent array, showing the search pattern

   ```
   // Depth First Search recursive helper method


   void DFS(Graph& G, int v0, Array<bool>* visited, Array<int>* search, int 
   depth)
   {

       // set visited
       (*visited)[v0] = true;

       // set search num
       (*search)[v0] = depth;

       // iterate through neighbors
       for (int i = 0; i < G.nodes(); i++)
       {
           // if i is a neighbor
           if (G.edge(i, v0))
           {
               // if it has not been visited
               if (!(*visited)[i])
               {
                    // call DFS
                    DFS(G, i, visited, search, depth + 1);
                }
            } // end if
        } // end for
   }

   // Depth First Search
   Array<int>* DFS(Graph& G, int v0)
   {

       // visited array
       Array<bool>* visited = new Array<bool>(G.nodes());

       // search number array, order of visitation
       Array<int>* search = new Array<int>(G.nodes());

       // initialize both arrays
       for (int i = 0; i < G.nodes(); i++)
       {
           (*visited)[i] = false;
           (*search)[i] = 1;
       }

       // create depth field
       int depth = 1;

       // call DFS
       DFS(G, v0, visited, search, depth);

       return search;

   };
   ```

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) for a good list of reasons as to why answers containing just links aren't necessarily good answers. Maybe update your answer to include a relevant code snippet from your link, along with an explanation of what the differences are and why it works.